# To access hidden Windows fileserver in local network

Tags: networking, windows-7, file-server

I know the name of the network, my username and password. 
The network is on Windows-7s filesharing.
However, I cannot see in FileBrowser, the network because it is apparently hidden.

I have done this in accessing the network folder of the fileserver

- In Windows Server, I see FileServer address is `\\masistrogage3.geek.meplease.fi` so I added it to Domain, instead of default `WORKGROUP`.
  I also tried `//masistorage3.geekmeplease.fi` with unix-like forward flashes but I think I should use those Windows-specific backward flashes also in the unix-box.
- username `masi`
- passsword `masimasi`

but I do not get in.

How can you connect to hidden networks in local network?

Comment: Which protocol? "network" is too generic. It is SMB, ssh, FTP, what else? If you have access to the two machines, and they are on the same physical net, using the IPs (`ifconfig` will show them) is normally ok, but how to use it depend on the sharing/network protocol.

Comment: @Rmano I add the info into the body of the question. Windows7 is the fileserver there which I am trying to access by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

1. on the server: find the IP address. In windows machines, I *think* you can run `ipconfig` in a terminal --- see [here](http://windows.about.com/od/networkconnect/a/How-To-Find-A-Computers-Ip-Address-In-Windows-7.htm).
2. In Ubuntu, open Files, and then choose "Connect to server":
   [image]
3. input `smb://you.ip.here./` --- if the server is configured to serve SMB shares and to list them, which are the default way of sharing in Windows, it should ask user and password, and let you browse the shares.

Otherwise, there can be literally millions of possible configurations ("literally, literally..." -cit.), and you should ask your system/network manager.

Comment: The address has backward flashes like `\\masistorage3.geek.meplease.fi`. Should I use the backward flashes in the unix box to access the server. Should I use the prefix `smb:\\` also?

Comment: That should be `smb://masistorage3.geek.meplease.fi/`